# Whether to use past or present tense with an "if"clause

Tags: tenses, past-tense, subjunctive-mood

Which is correct?

> George starts to realize how many lives he has changed and impacted, and how they would be different if he **was/were** never there.

Comment: I've added the [subjunctive] tag, which is what *were* would be interpreted as, but I think what is actually required is "...if he had never been there".

Comment: This sounds like Cliff Notes from _It's a Wonderful Life_.

Answer (score 2):

I think that here should use **"if he had never been there"**(past perfect) as this is the 3rd type of conditional sentence. Which means that it is an imaginary/improbable situation in the past.

in an other word, "If he was not existing in the past, the ones who were impacted would be different."

Comment: You know, I think I agree with you here.